# xcode location (installation path) help

Tags: xcode, macos

I am new to mac os. I started to deveople Iphone appliactions and it was strange to me cause I had to look in finder everytime to open xcode so I moved it in applications folder. 
But is not working anymore and I dont know where was the prevoius location in order to move there again.

Where should i put?

Plzz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open finder, select your hard disk on the right side, then go to `Developer -> Applications` and put Xcode there again. You can create a shortcut anywhere in your system.